# How do I search and fetch results while not being case sensitive?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have a python script that allows you to search the contents of a spreadsheet. The main problem is that everything is case sensitive so if I tried to search for "Tim", it won't give me results that are lowercase like "tim".

```py
values_re = re.compile(r'(?i)' + username)
values = sheet.findall(values_re)
print(values)
```

I tried using regex but the solution doesn't work and I still get hit with a no results error.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Default behavior of re.compile is that it is case sensitive so we need to flag the regex to ignorecase.

### Solution

You can use **re.IGNORECASE** in the re.compile part of your code. You can remove the r'(?i)' part of your code since it would be redundant. It should look like this:

```
values_re = re.compile(username, re.IGNORECASE)
```